# What happens to a quantum mechanical system if it is measured using a Projector that is orthogonal to the state of the system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I was wondering what actually happens to a physical system once it is subjected to a projective measurement.

Let's suppose the system is a qubit in the state $|1\rangle$. If I apply $|1\rangle\langle 1|$, the measurement result is $1$ and the qubit remains in the state $|1\rangle$.

But applying $|0\rangle \langle 0|$ gives the result $0$, meaning no state at all. Does that mean that the state is always destroyed when subjected to an orthogonal projection?

Or should I interpret the result as $|0\rangle\langle 0|1\rangle = 0 \times |0\rangle$, meaning that the final state is $|0\rangle$ with a measurement result of $0$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quantum measurement is a random process. You cannot "choose" which outcome you get. This is reflected in the fact that a projective measurement always corresponds to a *complete set* of projectors $\lvert \phi_i\rangle \langle\phi_i\rvert$, such that
$$ \sum_i \lvert \phi_i\rangle \langle\phi_i\rvert = 1. $$
There is no such thing as "measuring a projector".

Given a two-level system in state $\lvert \psi\rangle$, a measurement in the basis $\{\lvert 0\rangle\langle 0\rvert,\lvert 1\rangle\langle 1\rvert\}$ gives one of the two outcomes $\{\lvert 0\rangle,\lvert 1\rangle\}$ with probability 
$$P_j = \lvert \langle j\rvert\psi\rangle\rvert^2  $$
for $j= 0,1$. In your example, $\lvert \psi\rangle = \lvert 1\rangle$ and therefore the outcome $\lvert 1\rangle$ occurs with probability $P_1 = 1$. The outcome $\lvert 0\rangle$ has probability $P_0= 0$, i.e. it simply does not occur.

Comment: Dammit, too slow. Saw this on review and thought I'd answer, but of course The Shot got there first.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty :) tbh I'm surprised this question isn't essentially a dupe? I haven't really searched to check...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to both questions is no.

You should interpret the result as telling you that the outcome $|0\rangle$ has probability $0$, hence the outcome is $|1\rangle$ with probability $1$.

Comment: p.s: I edited my answer. I replied initially too quickly before my lunch, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You have mistaken a “projective measurement” for a “measurement after projection”. If you have an orthogonal projector, your wavefunction indeed ‘disappears’, and you will measure nothing afterwards. A projective measurement will just give you an outcome as described by Mark Mitchison.

Comment: @user203467 Then ask a new question.  Oh, and: Don't tag it [measurement-problem].

Comment: What happened?.

Comment: I guess the OP deleted some of their comments.

Comment: @Antaios Yes I posted a reply which contained a question but later noticed that my question didn't make a lot of sense. Thanks to your answer and that if Mark Mitchison, I realized that had hadn't fully understood what a “projective measurement” is.